# Retrieve parent document ID date for each document

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Documents` with 3 columns (see first 3 columns below).

Each document has a document date and a parent document. I want to make a select from the table, adding column `ParentDocIDDate` that lists the `docDate` of the `parentDoc` for each document. Notice that the parent for each parent document is the `parentDocID` itself.

```
docID    parentDocID    docDate        ParentDocIDDate
------------------------------------------------------
  1          3          2015-09-13     2016-01-07
  2          3          2015-10-30     2016-01-07
  3          3          2016-01-07     2016-01-07
  4          5          2017-03-03     2017-06-10
  5          5          2017-06-10     2017-06-10
```

Can anyone explain me how to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
select t1.docID, t1.parentDocID, t1.docDate, t2.docDate as ParentDocIDDate 
from table t1 
left join table t2 on t2.docID = t1.parentDocID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select A.*, B.docDate AS ParentDocIDDate  from TABLE_NAME AS A join TABLE_NAME AS B on A.docID = B.parentDocID
```